# Capybara undefined method `expect' for Capybara:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am using /ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/capybara-2.4.4 and /ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0.

My Capybara config:

```
      config.default_driver = :selenium
      config.run_server = false
      config.default_selector = :css
      config.default_wait_time = 60
```

I can assure you following methods work fine

```
     Capybara.visit
     find(:css, "#checkbox-selectall").set(true)
```

The only thing that is not working is the 'expect'

```
     expect(page).to have_css('.screen-reader-text')
```

or
         Capybara.expect(page).to have_css('.screen-reader-text')

I get the following error

```
     undefined method `expect' for Capybara:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I can clearly see in the documentation that this version of capybara does support the expect method but i am unable to understand why it is saying NoMethodError as if i am not calling it from the right scope or something.

Capybara Docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara

Comment: Not sure, but `expect` comes from rspec, are you using rspec too?

Comment: i just tried adding that library on top of my class like "require 'capybara/rspec'" but still getting the same error. Is that what you meant ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install RSpec -- put it in your gemfile, next to Capybara

`gem 'rspec'`

run `bundle install`

Generate an install
`rails generate rspec:install`, more info here https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Be sure to include capybara and your capybara settings in the new helper file (spec_helper or rails_helper).

Comment: Is there a way to have 'expect' method without having to use Rails? I'm using capybara same way as @Qambar and I really don't want to have to install rails just to use capybara.